# why type of Text.Parsec.Token.natural is not the same between Hoogle and what's showed with :t?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, parsec

I searched for `Text.Parsec.Token.natural` on Hoogle and found the type of `Text.Parsec.Token.natural` is `natural :: ParsecT s u m Integer`.

But that is contradictory to what I got with `:t` in GHCi.

GHCi gives this type:

```
Prelude Text.Parsec.Token> :t natural
natural
  :: GenTokenParser s u m -> Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT s u m Integer
```

And not only natural, so are integer, float, decimal, etc.

Comment: It's a bit confusing, isn't it? `hoogle` doesn't really know what type things have, it gets its information from `haddock` (usually, there are - or used to be - other ways). And the way `haddock` generates documentation for data types with named fields corresponds to how they are defined, `data Stuff = Value { field :: Int }`, and not what the type of the accessor function is, `field :: Stuff -> Int`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`natural` is a *named field* of the data type [`GenTokenParser s u m`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html#t%3aGenTokenParser). That field has type `ParsecT s u m Integer`; scroll down to find it.

The *function* `natural` accesses that field from any value of `GenTokenParser s u m`, hence the type.